# MySQL singling out multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I have a database which logs users events.
A simplified table looks like this

```
userid    eventtype     lastupdate
1          sent          5
1          opened        10
1          clicked       15
2          sent          5
3          sent          5
```

I'm trying to get the userid's that have the sent eventtype but not the opened OR clicked eventtype between a range of lastupdate.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (`eventtype` != "opened" AND (`lastupdate` BETWEEN 0 AND 10)) OR (`eventtype` != "clicked" AND (`lastupdate` BETWEEN 0 AND 10))
```

Is as far as I got, but will obviously not work since it will grab userid 1, 2 and 3.

While I want it to grab only 2 and 3.

The actual table is much more complicated as it also has to work with joins and some other columns, but if we can figure this part out I can do the rest.

Comment: Users `2` and `3` *have both the sent eventtype but not the opened OR clicked eventtype between a range of lastupdate*. So your query should select them also, or not?

Comment: which is good. from this table I would only want to return userid 3 and 2

Comment: Users `2` and `3` have *identical* `evettype` and `lastupdate` data. So why shouldn't `3` be selected?

Comment: Sorry sorry sorry. I meant 2 and 3. It's Friday >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable AS t1
WHERE lastupdate BETWEEN 0 AND 10 
      AND eventtype = 'sent'
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM mytable AS t2
                      WHERE t1.userid = t2.userid 
                            AND t2.lastupdate BETWEEN 0 AND 10 
                            AND t2.eventtype IN ('opened', 'clicked'))
```

The above will select users:

- whose `lastupdate` is `BETWEEN 0 AND 10` **and**
- have in this interval an `eventtype = 'sent'` **and**
- *don't have* an `eventtype IN ('opened', 'clicked')` *within the same interval*.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2cd41/1)

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it is in the right direction. The problem is I also have to inner join the table.

But This won't work will it:

SELECT * 
FROM email_list_subscribers INNER JOIN email_list_subscriber_events ON email_list_subscribers.subscriberid=email_list_subscriber_events.subscriberid AS t1

Comment: It works perfectly. You answered my question.
I still need it to join with the other table, but that was outside the scope of this question.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out the user_ids and I take your question literal, then this should be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT user_id 
  FROM events 
  WHERE eventtype NOT IN ('opened', 'clicked') 
    AND lastupdate BETWEEN 0 AND 10
  GROUP BY user_id;
```

This indeed will also select user_ids 2 and 3, since they too have sent matching events...

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. This query has me running up the walls. 
If we look at this example table, I would want it to return userid 2 and 3. (The inactive users)

Comment: Sorry, but that additional comment confused the question even more. Above you first say all users, then not 2 and 3, now only 2 and 3. I give up.

Comment: No problem. @Giorgos Betsos understood what I meant and he provided a solution. Thank you for your time and effort though. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this without any exists clauses, maybe it suits your needs

```
   select *
   from tst 
   where userid not in (
   select userid from tst where eventtype in ('opened', 'clicked'))
   and lastupdate between 0 and 10;
```

Tested it: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1836/1/0)